# java play framework override annotation failing with java.source=1.6

Tags: java, frameworks, playframework, overriding

According to the document, 
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/configuration#java

if I define java.source in conf/application.conf then I should be able to apply @Override annotations to methods that implement an interface, but I'm still getting compilation failures as though java. 1.5 is being used.

According to this page,
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/install

the version of java on the path will be used or the one at $JAVA_HOME if defined.

Both point to the same location which is jdk 6:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.8) (6b20-1.9.8-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)`
```

The error I'm getting is:

`The file BotRegexComparator.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The method compare(BotRegex, BotRegex) of type BotRegexComparator must override a superclass method`

Comment: is `BotRegexComparator` your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use a third party library which uses a Java version before 1.6, it won't work.

Comment: great thanks - that was the cause - spring 2.5.6 was the culprit in my case (migrating a spring app to play!)